Jackson XML ArrayList serialization
I have problem with serialization.
I have XML :
<ds:Transforms>
   <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped"/>
   <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC"/>
</ds:Transforms>

Tag Transform  is empty but has attribute.
Pojo Transforms:
@Data
public class Transforms {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Transform")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper
    private List<Transform> transform;
}

Pojo Transform:
@Data
public class Transform {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "Algorithm")
    private String algorithm;
}


When I serialize the given XML, the incoming result is:
Transforms(transform=[])

How could I get the list of two Transform with field algorithm ?

Just disable useWrapping attribute in the @JacksonXmlElementWrapper by putting false in Transforms class. It will work.
Updated code:
@Data
public class Transforms {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Transform")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Transform> transform;
}

Output on my local:
Transforms(transform=[Transform[algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped'], Transform[algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC']])


Thank you!
I tryed
 @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false, localname = "Transform")

And it didn't work, but your code works!
